# Password hashing on 32bit system then migrating to 64bit systems

Tags: java, php, python, encryption

I came across a potential issue when migrating from a 32bit system to a 64bit system.

the system runs two 'one way' encryption algos on the string.

However when I tried the same code on a 64 bit system the hashes were different, now thats fine but does anyone have any method on how to ensure the the hash can still be retreived and matched in the future when upgrading to 64bit and beyond?

Without risking the customers sensitive password? or ever storing the raw password or other sensitive data without encryption?

Comment: What hashing algorithm do you use? This should not happen with any on the common hashing algorithmns..

Comment: This shouldn't happen. The hash should be the same regardless of 32 or 64 bit architecture.  What language and libraries are you using to generate the hashes? What hash algorithm are you using? Your tags mention Java PHP and Python.  What language is actually having the problem? Or is it all 3?

Comment: *Real* hash algorithms have a well-defined, platform-independent output size. MD5 has 128 bits and that's a constant. What poor algorithm are you using that doesn't provide such a contract and is hence not usable across platforms?

Comment: The bit-size of the underlying system should have no effect on the results, merely how efficiently things are calculated. If you get different hashes, it's not directly due to the underlying OS version.

Comment: I assumed that the algos would behave differently on different bit systems, that was my assumption anyway :( . It seems i'm incorrect, however it's still churning out a different hash. thank you for your comments.

Comment: You almost certainly have problems in the hashing algorithm implementation. What is the algo you are using? Can you paste the code?

Comment: Another avenue to consider - a system-dependent salt which may be dependent on the arch OR you just may have never have noticed that the hashes were different even among 32 bit deployments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, just make sure that you're using the same algorithm.  If your hashes were different with the same inputs, you were using a different algorithm; there may be some unstated dependencies upon the underlying word size.  Make sure you don't use those types of algorithms, or if you do, that they have very clear expectations of the word sizes and that those things can be overridden by you.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will check it against this, I've realised due to the comments above its not bit size that can affect this. :( thanks again!